# Angular: How to share value from service to whole project angular 11?

Tags: angular

I have an issue with my angular project.
When I log in and save the data of my user to local storage and want to share it with the whole project to use it in every component, template without import UserService. Can you give me advice on how to solve the problem?
Thanks.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  // Get information of current user in local storage
  getCurrentUser(): IUser {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth-user'));
    return {
      _id: user?._id,
      avatarUrl: user?.avatarUrl,
      username: user?.username,
      bio: user?.bio,
    };
  }
}
```

Sorry! My English is rather bad.

Comment: What is the problem in importing the server. You can use it everywhere if you import the service and get the value. @jucnible

Comment: The main purpose of the service is to be used by the components. If you really don't want, get the user from `localStorage` on your `ngOnInit` method to store it in variable in your component. Then you could use it on your template.

Comment: Currently, I'm using it that way. I import the service and declare, get the user to use it in the template. But, I really want to pass it for root, to use anywhere `without import`. Do you think that this is possible?

Comment: No, if you want to use it in templates without importing the service in the component, create a new component or directive that imports the service and show the user, or whatever you want to do

Comment: Yes @Alexis, This is the way we can use but that might not be a good code quality right? We should try not to write the same lines of code again and again. I don't see any wrong if you import the service where ever you need data. You can create a new service only for this kind of things and reuse them.

Comment: @hansmad. You cant create all those things if there is much data in the local storage right? User data keeps updating and we do update a lot of data in the user config. So creating the directive for all of them might not be a correct way

Comment: Thank everyone. Maybe I have to use this way.

Comment: @PrashanthDamam I am agree with you, I use service and import them in my components, so finally a method can be reuse, but here, the question was to find a way without importing services

Answer (score 0):

You can create reusable components or directives that take care of your user information.

```
<img appAvatarUrl />
Name: <span appUserName></span>
```

These components of course have to import `UserService`, but the consuming components don't need to know it.

```
@Component({
 selector: '[appUserName]'
 template: '{{user?.name}}'   
})
class UserNameComponent {
  user: User;
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}
  // ....
}


@Directive({
    selector: '[appAvatarUrl]'
})
export class AvatarUrlDirective {

    constructor(private userService: UserService, private element: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        const url = this.userService.getUser().avatarUrl;
        this.element.nativeElement.setAttribute('src', url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @hansmaad. I like thí way but it's not suitable for my project. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that you might like better.
Add user as an observable to `UserService`, inject the service as public and directly reference the observable in templates using the `async` pipe.

```
export class UserService {
  user$ = new BehaviourSubject<IUser>(null);

  update(user: IUser) { this.user$.next(user); }
}
```

```
@Component({/*...*/}) class SomeComponent {
    constructor(public usr: UserService) {}
}
```

```
  <div>{{ (usr.user$ | async).name }}</div>
  <div>{{ (usr.user$ | async).bio }}</div>
  <app-some-pure-user-component [user]="usr.user$ | async" />
```